# Retrofit Https call give Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, spring-boot, retrofit2

I'm trying to use `retrofit` in my `spring boot` project to access a `https` call, but every time I run it, it gives

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:242) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:200) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:174) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:196) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:132) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:101) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63) ~[okhttp-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) ~[retrofit-2.1.0.jar:na]
```

My implementation is the following:

```
public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Utils.BASE_URL)
            .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().retryOnConnectionFailure(true).connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

and the call:

```
Service service = service.retrofit.create(Service.class);
Call<myObject> call = service.callService();
call.execute().body();
```

**UPDATE**
I added `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` to my `jvm` and I got the following output:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1482447462 bytes = { 90, 39, 6, 215, 111, 143, 240, 128, 196, 112, 178, 59, 97, 245, 196, 32, 59, 178, 217, 232, 1, 178, 221, 33, 93, 26, 143, 120 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api-test]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 189
http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
http-nio-8080-exec-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: The solution I found is to use Curl, it works, but never got it to work with retrofit

Answer (score 4):

Changing the url from http to https fixed the issue for me.
I was using http://testthesms.000webhostapp.com/...... instead of https://testthesms.000webhostapp.com.....
Though some other request went through the http.

Answer (score 2):

Change your url to HTTPS. It works for me

Comment: This is true. But notice that some guys are adding Network config(https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)  to Force HTTP over the HTTPS and causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, very similar like yours, it was problem with TLS protocol level.

The server was closing connections because don't accept protocols under TLS 1.2. And my retrofit client was running under Java 7 which uses TLS 1.1 by default, so server always reject all the connections.

The solution was to set TLS 1.2 as default protocol for Java VM client connections. The problem is fixed automatically is you change to Java 1.8+

Comment: This answer needs very much attention from those companies that force the android developers to support older API Versions forever! (In this case API < 21)
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was sending an object using *retrofit* and receiving the same object with the id value of an insert into the database.

The problem was that I have added two properties in my server side class, but I forgot to add those two properties in my client class (we know the two classes of exchanging data must be the same with the same properties) and I got the

> socket timeout exception: connection was reset

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

In my case, retrofit variable was not declared static.
So I changed

```
protected Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofit();
```

To

```
protected static Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofit();
```

and now the error's gone.